# Simulator app for facebook- iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode5, ios-simulator

I have used Facebook iOS api & to use some of permission, i have to submit them simulator build So they can review & allow me usage of API. Can you tell me where to find simulator build in XCODE 5?

Comment: Facebook ios sdk already works with simulator .

Answer (score 1):

struggling with the same issue here.

Facebook has a "tutorial" of how to build the binary at:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/creating-ios-simulator-build-for-review/

For my project we are using cocoapods and this makes thing more complicated.
I get loads of warnings like:

```
warning: no rule to process file '/Users/flip/poseidon/Pods/Facebook-iOS-SDK/src/Login/FBAccessTokenData.m' of type sourcecode.c.objc for architecture i386
```

It tells me the build completed, I get an .app file in ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ but I do not know how to test or it is working.

What I wonder is whether you can just build your project in the simulator and use the .app file that got created there?

Does anyone know or this is possible?